# Standard conventions or good practices when naming local/remote interfaces of EJBs?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, domain-driven-design

Are there any conventions or good practices when naming interfaces for EJBs? I am trying to apply some DDD principles in my application as well so I am using the "service" sterotype on the classes that is the interface for the world outside.

If I have a QuestionService EJB that provides business logic operations to clients, what would the @Local/@Remote Interface be named? All the books I read so far only names them QuestionServiceLocal/QuestionServiceRemote. Is this suffcient (I am not trying to get fancy with naming, but I wonder if there are better naming conventions)?

Also, are the other/better ways of naming the "services" in an application than just adding the "...Service" suffix on each class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java naming conventions are created and adopted by the community and also by the elder developers in the company.
So every time we are facing naming issues, we can go forward with the following:

1. if the project is already there then just follow the project naming
   coventions
2. if this is a new project you're creating then:
   a. `QuestionServiceLocal`/`QuestionServiceRemote` is a very good approach
   b. `QuestionService` is more than enough for naming a service

Comment: Unfortunatly I am working alone at the moment and being a student I do not have other project conventions to turn to.

Comment: Then the conventions you mentioned are great dont try to work out other ones because the people that will come after you to work on your projects will be confused