# naming convention for domain services and application services with DDD

Tags: java, domain-driven-design, naming-conventions

In DDD approach, what is the best-practice for naming domain services components and application services components ?

For instance, should I have within my application layer a service named : RoomReservationService
and in my domain layer a service named also RoomReservationService; the first delegating to the other ?

Actually, when an application service does not gather many domain services, that means I can't find distinct names between them, how could I name it without introducing any confusion ?

Comment: Look at this thread, it talks all about it. [enter][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10065065/standard-conventions-or-good-practices-when-naming-local-remote-interfaces-of-ej

Comment: Thanks, I've just read it but it only deals with remote services ( application services) and not with internal services (domain services).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In DDD You can use the same approach as remote services applications:

Application layer service name : `RoomReservationService`
In package name : `com.my.package.service.RoomReservationService`

Domain layer service name : `RoomReservationDomainService`
In package name : `com.my.package.domain.service.RoomReservationDomainService`